# How to handle fail situation into a simple Java application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture, exception

I am a Java developer but I have not yet got a lot of experience in software architecture.

I have the following situation. I am creating a batch application (a command line application that run into the shell) so it is started from a **main()** method defined into a **Main()** class.

Into this **main()** method I create some objects instances of other classes that do something (such as performing query on a DB, create PDF, etc) so here the application could fail.

If the application don't fail (everything went as expected) the **main()** method end with an **exit code = 0**.

I want that if the application fail (at any point) the returned **exit code is -1**.

So now I don't know how I have to handle this situation.

For example if into the **main()** method I have something like this:

```
// Create DAO object:
FatturaDAO fatturaDAO = new FatturaDAO(conn);
listaFatture = fatturaDAO.getListaFatturePDF(partitaIVA);
```

in which I create and use a **DAO** object. Considering now the case in which something fail into the **FatturaDAO** object (for example connection is lost and an exception is thrown).

How correctly handling this situation?

I have 2 ideas but I don't know what is the best solution:

1. I put some try catch blocks inside my code so if something fails it enter into the **catch** block that handle it performing a:

   ```
   System.exit(-1);
   ```
2. If something fail it enter into the **catch** block that instead of exit throws a custom exception that goes back until the **main()** method that perform:

   ```
   System.exit(-1);
   ```

Or maybe can I handle these situations in some other smarter way?

Comment: Have a look at [`Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In command line applications, the main() method is effectively the UI layer.  It's a very bare-bones UI, but still, if you structure your app so that the main class is invoking a controller layer, and the controller layer is throwing an exception, you should catch that exception in the main() method, and return the correct "user value" of 0 or -1.

Comment: And what problem can I perform a System.exit(-1); inside the other object created inside the main()?

Comment: Don't, throw an exception inside the other object, catch it in the main, and render the "UI" in the main only.

Comment: Ok, but what is it the motivation?

Comment: The motivation is to separate UI concerns from business logic concerns.   Lets say you take this batch processing away from being a command-line process, and hook it up to a queue, or a database.  System.exit() is inappropriate for those scenarios, they have different interfaces (logging error, or inserting error rows in database, etc).

Comment: Tnx for your clarification :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
2. If something fail it enter into the catch block that instead of exit 
throws  a custom exception that goes back until the main() method that perform:
```

If you are handling exceptions in `main()` then you have to have error handling code at the parent level. If there's any change there's no need to check other functions, you just need to add the `through` keyword on the other functions and handle the exception in `main()` and return the required type.

In most J2EE applications we handle exceptions in the `Controller` part not the `DAO` or `Service` layers. It is easier to pass messages to users when exceptions happen.